# How to insert new Products and Price Book using Apex Dataloader

Tags: data-loader, salesforce-id, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

Do anybody know How to insert new Products and Price Book using Apex data loader. Every 1 product will have more that 1 price in price book. please guide me to possible ways to do.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you, I was looking for information on this myself and found the following information from the Salesforce boards quite useful.

[Developer Force](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Data-Loader-and-Price-book-problem/td-p/249021)

> How to insert/upload new Products, Price Books & Opportunity Line Item
>   via Data Loader?
>
> Questions this solution will help answer:
>
> Step 1: How do I create and activate a Product Price Book?
>
> Step 2: How do I load Products via the Data Loader?
>
> Step 3: How do I load Products into Standard Price Book and Custom Price Books via the Data Loader?
>
> Step 4: How do I load Opportunity Line Items via the Data Loader?
>
> The following steps need to be taken in the exact order:
>
> ---
>
> How do I create and activate a Product Price Book?
>
> **Step 1** - SET UP Price Books in Salesforce CRM Usually there are only a
>   small finite set of price books, therefore this action can be done
>   directly in the application. If you choose to use the Data Loader, use
>   the "PriceBook2" table.
>
> 1. In salesforce click on the Products Tab.
> 2. In the bottom right-hand corner, click on "Manage Price Books"
> 3. Add as many Price Books as necessary.
> 4. The Standard Price Book MUST be active.
>
> ---
>
> How do I load Products via the Data Loader?
>
> **Step 2a** - PREPARE Products file (See attached template
>   "Products_INSERT_Template_Step2a.csv")
>
> 1. Make sure all Products have a Product Name 
>      -This is a required field when loading Products into the "Products2" Table
> 2. If you use Record Types, you will need the "RecordTypeID" for the insert file
>      -EXPORT "Record Type" table via the Force.com AppExchange Data Loader (you will need to check "Show all Sforce Objects"). This export will
>      provide the 18 digit ID, which is needed for the insert.
> 3. Make sure your column headers in the file exactly match fields in SFDC
>
> **Step 2b** - INSERT Products to the "Products2" Table.
>
> 1.Open Data Loader 
>   2. Insert to "Products2" table
>   3. Save success and error files in a folder for this project, you will use them in the Step 3b.
>
> ---
>
> How do I load Products into Standard Price Book and Custom Price Books
>   via the Force.com AppExchange Data Loader?
>
> **Step 3a** - EXPORT "Price Book 2" Table  You will need the
>   "PriceBook2ID's" and other fields to prepare a file for the next step.
>
> 1. Open the Data Loader
> 2. Export the "Price Book 2" table
> 3. You need "Price Book 2 ID" for insert file
> 4. Save file in an easy to access location
> 5. This will be used to create your final insert file for Step 3c and 3e
>
> **Step 3b** - PREPARE file for Standard Price Book
>
> *NOTE: Even if you do not want to associate these Products with the
>   Standard Price Book this step still must be followed.*
>
> Data Columns: 
>   -Product2ID: Use the "ID" from the "Product2" success file from Step 2
>   -PriceBook2ID: get the Standard Price Book ID from file created in Step 3a
>   -CurrencyIsoCode: use Salesforce CRM currency symbol (only for Multi-Currency org)
>   -Unit Price: this is the List Price/Standard Price field for the product
>   -UseStandardPrice: this should be TRUE or FALSE and indicates whether to use the price from Standard Price Book or not.
>   ----FALSE (only option for Standard Price Book)
>   ----TRUE (is not an option because "Use Standard Price" field is not available in the Standard Price Book)
>   -IsActive: TRUE (must be TRUE to insert - this can be changed to FALSE after Step 5 is complete)
>
> **Step 3c** - INSERT into "Price Book Entry" Table
>
> 1. Open the Data Loader
> 2. Insert to "Price Book Entry" table
> 3. Save success and error files in a folder for this project
>
> **Step 3d** - PREPARE file for Custom Price Books Use the file from last
>   step and modify it to have the Custom Price Book ID.
>
> Data Columns: 
>   -Product2ID: Use the "ID" from the "Product2" success file from Step 2
>   -PriceBook2ID: get the Custom Price Book ID from file created in Step 3a
>   -CurrencyIsoCode: use Salesforce currency symbol (only for Multi-Currency org)
>   -Unit Price: this is the List Price/Standard Price field for the product
>   -UseStandardPrice: this should be TRUE or FALSE and indicates whether to use the price from Standard Price Book or not.
>   ----FALSE (this choice means you will use the Unit Price from the custom Price Book and NOT the Unit Price from the Standard Price Book)
>   ----TRUE (this option only works if this Product has been added to the Standard Price Book. This choice will use the Unit Price from the
>   Standard Price Book)
>   -IsActive: TRUE
>
> **Step 3e** - INSERT into "Price Book Entry" Table  MAKE SURE your Custom
>   Price Books are Active in SFDC.
>
> 1. Open Data Loader
> 2. Insert to "Price Book Entry" table
> 3. Save success and error files in a folder for this project
>
> **Step 3f** (optional) INACTIVATE Standard Products in Standard Price Book
>
> 1. Take the success files the Standard Price Book Entry insert from step 3c
> 2. Change the values in "IsActive" from true to FALSE
> 3. Map only the "Product2ID" and "IsActive" fields
> 4. Open AppExchange Data Loader
> 5. UPDATE "Price Book Entry" Table
> 6. Save success and error files in a folder for this project
>
> ---
>
> How do I load Opportunity Line Items via the Data Loader?
>
> **Step 4** (optional) INSERT products into "OpportunitiesLineItem" Table
>
> 1. Data Columns: 
>      -Opportunity ID 
>      -PricebookEntryID 
>      -Total Price 
>      -Quantity 
>      -Unit price
>      -other fields as needed NOTE: The Opportunity Product Table provides the "ProductID" as a mappable field, however this field should not be
>      mapped in this process.
> 2. Export the Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItem) table for a template
> 3. Export the appropriate Opportunities from the data loader with filter criteria.
> 4. Copy OpportunityID into the insert/update template file.
> 5. Export the "Price Book Entry" table from the data loader, the "ID" column is the PricebookEntryID.
> 6. Copy the appropriate PricebookEntryID's (with corresponding Opportunities) into the insert/update file.
> 7. Add the other data into the relevant columns in the insert/update file.
> 8. Open AppExchange Data Loader.
> 9. Insert to "Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItem)" table

Comment: Hi Adam & welcome to StackExchange. I'm sure this answer would get upvotes if you'd improve it a bit. Links tend to expire and we're encouraged to write a bit more about solutions, show more content, potential pitfalls, samples etc rather than be effectively a redirect ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers